# How to write reg expression which uses some special characters?

Tags: regex, tcl

I would like to write reg expression which should not use special symbols other than (/, \, -, [, ], <, >, $, ~, !, @, #, :, %). So I try:

```
  if { [regexp {^[\w/-\[\]<>$#~!@#%:\\\/]+$} $name] != 1 } {
        puts "Handle error";
  }
```

But this not work.

For example for such name `IO1??` it's not treated as error

Could anyone help?

Comment: Black slash or front slash?

Comment: It seems like you just added a lot more chars to the initial post question of underscore, slashes, letters, numbers....  The way you are phrasing these new "requirements" make it confusing as to what is actually allowed.  Not use other than... the double negative makes it tricky to figure out exactly what you want.

Comment: Yes as far as I understand result should not be changed. Is it?

Comment: Should `IO1??` be allowed, or not allowed?   The post has gotten a lot more confusing with all the new additions and changes.

Comment: It's should not be allowed

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to escape the `-` in your character class or put it at the beginning - otherwise it's interpreted as a range:

```
regexp {^[\w/\-\[\]<>$#~!@#%:\\\/]+$} $name
```

or

```
regexp {^[-\w/\[\]<>$#~!@#%:\\\/]+$} $name
```

The range between `/` and `\[` seems to contain `?`.

Answer (score 2):

I am assuming you want both types of slash `/` and `\`.  You could try `^[\w\\\/]+$`  I tried some [examples here](http://rubular.com/r/1BSCgFlzMn).

You were close, but it seemed like you were only handling `/`.  You were correct in escaping it (needing `\/`).  If you add the extra `\\` you are allowing for `\` as well.

If this doesn't work, please provide some examples of some complex strings you are using that are passing/failing so we can help make the regex better.

NOTE: This answer was to the OP regarding just numbers, letters, underscores, and slashes.

Comment: Actually there are very few characters that need escaping inside character classes. `/` doesn't even need escaping outside character classes, unless used for delimiting or separation.